# SQL group by not getting top record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my sample records in my table.

Fields are varchar,
ToDate contain two empty records. (not am Database NULL)

```
CustomerID  FromDate    ToDate
1           20120810    20120920
2           20120901    20120915
3           20120112    
4           20120815    
5           20120817    20120920
6           20120817    20120920
```

Has to follow below rules:

1. Sort with furthest date in ToDate column.
2. When records is empty then took current date+30 instead of empty,
3. When two dates are same in the ToDate, then take furthest date in the FromDate.

So for the above records sample i need the output as

```
CustomerID   FromDate   ToDate
3            20120112   20130221
```

because customer id 4 and 5 ToDate are empty, so we consider should add 30 days from the getdate() function. So Todate are equal so i want to sort by FromDate now.

Input for the date is 20120810

```
select   top 1 customer_id, 
max(convert(datetime,Fromdate,101)) as Fromdate,
convert(datetime,(CASE WHEN Todate = '' THEN getdate() + 30 WHEN Todate != '' THEN Todate END),101) as Todate,
customer_id
FROM  dbo.sample_tbl (nolock)
 WHERE  customer_id = '1' 
 AND    Fromdate <= '20120810'
 AND    (CASE WHEN ToDate = '' THEN getdate() + 30 WHEN ToDate != '' THEN ToDate END) >= '20120810'
group by convert(datetime,(CASE WHEN ToDate = '' THEN getdate() + 30 WHEN ToDate != '' THEN ToDate END),101),customer_id
order by convert(datetime,(CASE WHEN ToDate = '' THEN getdate() + 30 WHEN ToDate != '' THEN ToDate END),101) desc
```

Current output is

```
CustomerID   FromDate  ToDate
3            20120112  20130221
```

Expected is

```
CustomerID   FromDate   ToDate
3            20120815   20130221
```

Comment: Why are you storing datetimes as varchar?

Comment: I must be being dense. Can you highlight the difference between "current" and "expected" please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i just updated, can u please check now.

Comment: You say "customer id 4 and 5 ToDate are empty" but that's not what your sample data says; this means I'm much less inclined to try to work out what on earth your requirements are.

Comment: i just used the order by todate desc, fromdate desc. and converted the getdate in to varchar. now problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think u code is too complex and redundant.
You should create a SQL function to get enddate.
Call this function getEndDate (String date) (I think you can create it by your own)

you query could be :

```
select  CustomerID  ,FromDate  , getEndDate (ToDate) 
from sample_tbl
order by getEndDate (ToDate) desc, FromDate  desc  ;
```

and you take the first row.

Comment: can u provide that function. i dont know

Comment: personaly I use Oracle not sql server. in pseudo code it should like that: function getEndDate(String startdate, string endDate) begin if endDate = '' then return startDate + 30 else return endDate) END.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer 2005+

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 ( 
  SELECT CustomerID,         
         MAX(CAST(FromDate AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY
         (CASE WHEN ToDate = '' THEN CAST(GETDATE() + 30 AS date) ELSE CAST(ToDate AS date) END
         )) AS FromDate,         
         CASE WHEN ToDate = '' THEN CAST(GETDATE() + 30 AS date) ELSE CAST(ToDate AS date) END AS ToDate
  FROM dbo.sample_tbl
  )
  SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID, MAX(FromDate) AS FromDate, ToDate
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY ToDate, CustomerID
  ORDER BY ToDate DESC
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/650ed/2/0)